# How to add dots for my pagination script

Tags: php, pagination

Hi i have a problem with script for pagination

I don't know how to add dots, when i have to much pages. Thanks for help.

```
for($l=1;$l<=$nbpages;$l++)
{
  if($_GET[page]!="")
  {
    $nlink=str_replace($link[$czlony-2], 'page-'.$l, 
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  else
  {
     $nlink='/tours/page-'.$l.'/';
   }

   echo '<li';
   if(($l==1)OR($l==$nbpages)OR(($l>$thispage-2)AND($l<$thispage+15))){
    //echo ' style="display:none"';
   }else{
     echo ' style="display:none"';
     }
 if(($_GET[page]==$l)OR(($l==1)AND($_GET[page]==''))){echo ' class="active" ';}

  echo'><a href="'.$nlink.'">'.$l.'</a></li> ';
}
```

Comment: What "dots" are you talking about?

Comment: They want to stop outputting links to specific pages after a certain stage. You need to decide how many page number links you want to display first. Then use `break;` to exit your loop.

Comment: This might help you: http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/php-mysql-pagination